# It seems my Centos 7 repo “updates” is not up to date

Tags: linux

I am trying to update my sudo package on Linux instances to remedy CVE-2021-3156. Some of Centos 7 boxes do not see required update `sudo-1.8.23-10.el7_9.1.x86_64.rpm`. I checked Centos 7 instances that successfully updated and their "Updates" repo stand at 1216 packages. The instances that fail to find update stand at 1174. I already ran command `yum clean all` but I am still getting the same count. Anybody know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does  sudo sudo -V say?  My Ubuntu machine (just did updates) is 1.8 plus and my Kali machine (just did updates) is 1.9.5 which seems to be up to date. I am going to try sudo update and sudo upgrade in Ubuntu instead of the Ubuntu updater.  Follow up - suggestion above did not work in Ubuntu. Still loolking

Comment: sudo-1.8.23-10.el7_9.1.x86_64.rpm package contains the fix. Just typing the version will not tell you the full story. For example. command `sudo yum list installed | grep sudo.x86_64` will tell you what package is installed. In my case it is sudo-1.8.23-10.el7 and not  sudo-1.8.23-10.el7_9.1 (which I need)

Comment: From ZD Net Jan 27 "CVE identifier of CVE-2021-3156, but is more commonly known as "Baron Samedit," was discovered by security auditing firm Qualys two weeks ago and was patched earlier today with the release of Sudo v1.9.5p2"  That is where my Kali machine is. But I think Ubuntu needs a Kernel update for this to happen and they have not yet done this. I do not use Ubuntu much, so I am going to wait for a bit.

Comment: I understand but my question is about Centos. I have no issues with Ubuntu instances.